# For all norm $N$, there exists $k>0$ such that $N(x) \le k|x|$ is valid for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

The exercise reads as follows: Let $x = (x_1,x_2, ...x_n) \in R^n$, $N$ an arbitrary norm and $|x|=max |x_i|$ prove that there exists a $k>0$ such that $N(x) \leqslant k|x|$ is valid for all $x \in R^n$.

This is waht I have done so far:

(1)Let $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$   and  $b=(b_1,...,b_n)$, for every $1\le i \le n, \ \ \  a_i>b_i \implies N(a) < N(b)$

If $x \ne 0$ then for every $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n\\
\frac{x_i}{|x|}\leq1<2 $

therefore $N(\frac{x}{|x|}) < N((2,2,...,2))\iff N(x) < N((2,2,...2))|x|$ by (1).

Equality comes from when $x=0$.

I would like to know if this is the right way to address the problem and if so how to prove (1).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: I already tried to but can´t figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e_1,...,e_n$ are the standard basis vectors then $x=(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i$. By the properties of a norm:

$N(x)=N(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^n N(x_ie_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|N(e_i)\leq\max_j|x_j|\sum_{i=1}^n N(e_i)=$

$=|x|\sum_{i=1}^n N(e_i)$

So $k=\sum_{i=1}^n N(e_i)$ works.